# How to get the next higher decimal value in java, rounded to one decimal place?

Tags: java, math

I have two doubles as follows: 011490.2 and 011500.1
I want to print all doubles within this range in java, rounded to one decimal place. How can I do that?

This is what I tried so far but it is going in some sort of infinity loop:

```
            Double a = Double.parseDouble(temp[0].subSequence(temp[0].indexOf("g")+1, temp[0].length()).toString());
            Double b = Double.parseDouble(temp[1].subSequence(temp[0].indexOf("g")+1, temp[1].length()).toString());
            int count = 0;
            while (b >= a) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("printing range:" + Math.round(Math.nextUp(a));

            }
```

I want something like this printed:
011490.2
011490.3
011490.4
011490.5
011490.6
011490.7
011490.8
011490.9
011490.2
011490.3
011490.4
011491.1
011491.2
011491.3
011491.4
011491.5
.
.
.
.
011500.1

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use an integer that counts from 114902 to 115001 and print this integer / 10.0. This avoids most of the rounding problems involved with floating point numbers.

Comment: But I wanted the decimals too up to 1 decimal point

Comment: That's why you should divide by 10.0

Comment: And your loop is infinite since neither `a` nor `b` changes inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double a = Double.parseDouble("011490.2");
double b = Double.parseDouble("011500.1");
int count = 0;
while (a <= (b + 0.1)) {
    System.out.printf("printing range: 0%.1f\n",a);
    a = a+0.1;
}
```

Output:

```
printing range: 011490.2
printing range: 011490.3
printing range: 011490.4
printing range: 011490.5
printing range: 011490.6
printing range: 011490.7
...
...
...
printing range: 011499.6
printing range: 011499.7
printing range: 011499.8
printing range: 011499.9
printing range: 011500.0
printing range: 011500.1
```

Comment: Better turn that into `double a`... there is absolutely no point in using Double as type here. It is ok for parsing, but not for computations!

Comment: 011490.2 is supposed to print according to the question

Comment: @GhostCat can you explain me a bit more on why `double` is a better choice that `Double`

Comment: Double are immutable objects. Your code creates a ton of intermediate objects, which all get thrown away afterwards. If you don't know such basic things, you should be really careful about giving other people advice in Java.

Comment: @PankajSinghal look at your output. Unless you have updated the code but not the answer, 011490.2 is not yet printing. I'm not saying it is hard to do, just that technically that is what the question wanted.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thanks, Updated.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks. Have updated the answer. Also, I think SO is here so that we all could learn from each other while helping each other. And being a senior member such as yourself, you should encourage helping behaviour & correct something which seems incorrect with appropriate reasoning so that the other person could also learn, instead of teasing about not knowing things.

Comment: I think I just did so. And I am not *teasing* you. You have to understand that many people might read your input in the future. It is perfectly fine to give answers about things where you aren't sure or know everything. But when you put up concrete, specific advice (as in: code examples) ... you should really know what you are doing. That is all I am saying. I give answers from time to time where I am not 100% sure ... but then I give a disclaimer in my answer about that.

Answer (score 3):

For completness, here's the `for` loop way:

```
    double start = 11490.2D;
    double end = 11500.1D;

    for(double i = start; i < end + 0.05; i += 0.1) {
        System.out.printf("%.1f\n", i);
    }
```

EDIT: updated based on Henry's comment

Comment: Due to rounding effects, the value `end` may not be printed with this loop. Better use a condition like: `i < end + 0.05`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my variant

```
double a = 11490.2;
double b = 11500.1;

while (a <= (b + 0.01)) {
    System.out.printf("0%.1f ", a); //Change to System.out.printf("0%.1f \n", a); if you want each value on a new row
    a += 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    do {
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(a));
        a = a + 0.1;
    } while (b >= a);

    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(a));
```

Comment: The question wants to print 011490.2, which this will not. You could add that outside the loop.